# Remove `UIImagePickerController` zoom slider

Tags: ios, camera, zooming, uiimagepickercontroller

How can I remove the zoom slider from the `UIImagePickerController`? It appears when the user tries to zoom in.

Comment: imagePickerController.allowsEditing = NO ?

Comment: Your solution works partially. I still want to let the user zoom in/out, but without showing the slider.

Comment: Then you'll need to implement a UIPanGesture programatically.

Comment: Did you find any solution. I also want to do the zoom but do not want to see the slider as it is overlapping my camera overlay view which is kind of annoying.

Comment: I am trying to find a solution and will post it if I find one.

Answer (score 1):

Do you still want to use the zoom ? Because you can set to NO the user interaction of of the UIImagePickerController's view. The user wont be able to zoom and so the zoom in wont show.

self.imagePicker.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

Comment: This also makes the buttons untappable.